# Numpy/Pandas correlate 2 arrays of different length

Tags: python, numpy, math, pattern-matching, pearson-correlation

I'm trying to calculate correlation coefficient for 2 datasets which are not of same length. The below code works only for equal length arrays.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr

a = [0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5]
b = [25, 40, 62, 58, 53, 54]

print pearsonr(a, b)
```

In my case the `b` vector length can vary from 50 - 100 datpoints. While the function I want to match is standard. Attached image of `a`. Is there any other preferred modules to match such patterns?

[image]

Comment: To calculate a correlation coefficient you have to know how points in `a` match the ones in `b`. So if the size of `b` varies, how do you know which points in `a` map to `b`? This seems more like a math issue vs. a numpy one.

Comment: I agree. I have added relevant tags now. I was hoping if someone has same issue to solve with python/numpy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Little late for the party, but since this is a Google top result, I'll throw a possible answer to this problem:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr 
import numpy as np 


a = [ 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.45, 0.2, 0.52, 0.52, 0.4, 0.21, 0.2, 0.4, 0.51]
b = [ 0.4, 0.2, 0.5]


df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=a))

CORR_VALS = np.array(b)
def get_correlation(vals):
    return pearsonr(vals, CORR_VALS)[0]

df['correlation'] = df.rolling(window=len(CORR_VALS)).apply(get_correlation)
```

#### Explanation

`pandas` DataFrames have `rolling()` method that takes array length length (`window`) as argument. The object that is returned from `rolling()` has [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) method that takes function as an argument. You can calculate for example the [Pearson Correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) using [pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) from scipy.stats.

#### Example output

```py
In [2]: df['correlation'].values
Out[2]:
array([        nan,         nan, -0.65465367,  0.94491118, -0.94491118,
        0.98974332, -0.94491118,  0.9923356 , -0.18898224, -0.75592895,
       -0.44673396,  0.1452278 ,  0.78423011,  0.16661846])
```

[image]

#### With the example data in the question

```py
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
     x  correlation
0  0.0          NaN
1  0.4          NaN
2  0.2          NaN
3  0.4          NaN
4  0.2          NaN
5  0.4     0.527932
6  0.2    -0.159167
7  0.5     0.189482
```

Answer (score 3):

You essentially can't calculate the correlation coefficient between vectors of different lengths, as you need paired data for the computation. You could maybe interpolate the shortest vector in order to make them the same length, but this could significantly change the results, depending on the interpolation method.