# Numpy/Pandas correlate multiple arrays of different length

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, data-science, pearson-correlation

I can correlate two arrays of different length using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487046/numpy-pandas-correlate-2-arrays-of-different-length):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr

a = [0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5]
b = [25, 40, 62, 58, 53, 54]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=a))

CORR_VALS = np.array(b)
def get_correlation(vals):
    return pearsonr(vals, CORR_VALS)[0]

df['correlation'] = df.rolling(window=len(CORR_VALS)).apply(get_correlation)
```

I get a result like this:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 

    x  correlation
0  0.0          NaN
1  0.4          NaN
2  0.2          NaN
3  0.4          NaN
4  0.2          NaN
5  0.4     0.527932
6  0.2    -0.159167
7  0.5     0.189482
```

First of all, the pearson coeff should just be the highest number in this dataset...

Secondly, how could I do this for multiple sets of data? I would like an output like I would get in df.corr(). With the indices and columns labeled appropriately.

for example, say I have the following datasets:

```
a = [0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5]
b = [25, 40, 62, 58, 53, 54]
c = [ 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.45, 0.2, 0.52, 0.52, 0.4, 0.21, 0.2, 0.4, 0.51]
d = [ 0.4, 0.2, 0.5]
```

I want a correlation matrix of sixteen Pearson coeffs...

Comment: The Pearson R should exist between [-1, 1]... Regardless it's unclear what you mean by correlation for this because technically it's undefined for unequal length vectors. The solution you point to determines the correlation of the smaller vector with all contiguous subsets from the larger vector (hence you get a rolling array of correlations), but 1) it's unclear what signular value you'd want from that and 2) that now makes no sense when you do this pairwise with multiple vectors, how do you even organize all of these unrelated rolling correlations?

Comment: Interpolation onto a regular grid is another alternative, but that comes with a whole other set of assumptions that only you can decide are appropriate or not.

Comment: @ALollz Yes, the Pearson R should exist between [-1,1]. the datasets a, b, c, d, are not coeffs, incase that's what you interpreted. 1) I want the pearson coeff, when the two datasets correlate the highest, which is the highest number. I understand it is scanning the smaller vector along the larger one, but why doesn't it return the max value (the pearson coeff)?

Comment: @ALollz 2 )I don't want to organize any unrelated correlations, I want to organize the related correlations, i.e. the pearson coeffs. I want an organized grid like that in df.corr() of the most correlated coeffs. Some of these vectors get "cut-off" in data collection. I want to see if they were at least correlated before they stopped collecting data.

Comment: You should change the data based on it's distribution to get an acceptable result or you are just making useless numbers to show and they don't mean any thing. you can use `scipy.signal.resample` to make them having the same length. After that use pearsonr or any other method to get their correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr

a = [0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5]
b = [25, 40, 62, 58, 53, 54]
c = [ 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.45, 0.2, 0.52, 0.52, 0.4, 0.21, 0.2, 0.4, 0.51]
d = [ 0.4, 0.2, 0.5]

# To store the data
dict_series = {'a': a,'b': b,'c':c,'d':d}
list_series_names = [i for i in dict_series.keys()]

def get_max_correlation_from_lists(a, b):
    # This is to make sure the longest list is in the dataframe
    if len(b)>=len(a):
        a_old = a
        a = b
        b= a_old
    # Taking the body from the original code.
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=a))
    CORR_VALS = np.array(b)
    def get_correlation(vals):
        return pearsonr(vals, CORR_VALS)[0]
    # Collecting the max
    return df.rolling(window=len(CORR_VALS)).apply(get_correlation).max().values[0]

# This is to create the "correlations" matrix
correlations_matrix = pd.DataFrame(index=list_series_names,columns=list_series_names )
for i in list_series_names:
    for j in list_series_names:
        correlations_matrix.loc[i,j]=get_max_correlation_from_lists(dict_series[i], dict_series[j])

print(correlations_matrix)
          a         b         c         d
a       1.0  0.527932  0.995791       1.0
b  0.527932       1.0   0.52229  0.427992
c  0.995791   0.52229       1.0  0.992336
d       1.0  0.427992  0.992336       1.0
```